# Cygwin usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter : Permission denied

Tags: perl, cygwin

Hello I'm trying to run a perl script on a Windows 64 bit. I'm getting the error like this :

> /usr/bin/perl : bad interpreter : Permission denied

I have my perl script on my windows 64 bit `C:\test\perlscripts\testperl.pl`.

Comment: Are you invoking the script from a cygwin shell or a windows shell?  If you're trying to run it from Windows (either a cmd shell or double clicking on it in Explorer) you won't be able to use Cygwin paths/interpreters.

Comment: I'm invoking the script from a cygwin shell.

Comment: Did you create the file using a Windows editor?  If so there could be a stray \r at the end of the line so the real interpreter it's trying to invoke is `/usr/bin/perl^M`?  From the shell can you run /usr/bin/perl and have it actually execute perl?

Comment: Show the first few lines of your script including the [shebang line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/100754). Also include the hexdump of the first few lines: From the Cygwin bash shell: `head testperl.pl | od` ... I am guessing you have an extrac CR following the `perl` on the shebang line.

Comment: i had similar problem but issue was not related . putting it in comment so that it may help somebody. In case you are not using C drive for the executable cygwin will never be able to find the same. Keep all the program in C drive for cygwin to work on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably saved the Perl script with DOS style [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). The shell is looking for a file called `/usr/bin/perl<CR>`.

Save your files with Unix-style line endings. My `.vimrc` which I use with my natively compiled `vim` and `gvim` has:

```
set fileformat=unix
set fileformats=unix,dos
```

Check your editor's settings for the appropriate options.

To fix line endings in a particular file, use `$ dos2unix filename`.

Answer (score 2):

You may not install `Perl` in default cygwin64 package. Please ensure that you have `Perl` at `/usr/bin/perl.exe`.

If it is not there, run `setup-x86_64.exe` again and select `Perl` interpreter.

Comment: This worked for me when the error quoted by the OP arose trying to use autoreconf in cygwin.